# UITableView Scroll memory warning swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, lazy-loading

Im using `Swift 2`, and Im facing a problem in `UITableView` scrolling.

My `UITableView` has large amount of cells/records and when I scroll the `tableview`, the memory increases as the cell created again and again and memory warning occur in `didReceiveMemoryWarning()` and it crashes !!!

In Objc, we can achieve the cell creation in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    // Create cell
}
```

But How can I manage this in `Swift 2` ? How can I optimise my `UITableView` for scrolling for large number of cells with image loading as well.

My Code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


            let node = dataSource[indexPath.row]

if let theLabel = self.viewWithTag(1009) as? UILabel {
            theLabel.text = node.TEXT 
        }

           // More setting labels and image as well


        return cell!

    }
```

EDIT 1:

Actually Im also adding a subview which has image handling,

```
if let view = self.viewWithTag(1008) as? UIView {
                let controller = self.getViewControllerWithIdentifier("MY_SUBVIEW") as! MY_SUBVIEW
            controller.arraySource = node
            self.containerAddChildViewController(controller, withRootView: view!)
            }
```

And the subview class is:

```
    import UIKit

    class MY_SUBVIEW: UIViewController {

        var arraySource: NSArray?


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            loadData()
        }


        func loadData() {


             if let theLabel = self.viewWithTag(1007) as? UILabel {
                    theLabel.text = arraySource[0]["label"]
                }
            if let imageView = self.viewWithTag(1006) as? UIImageView {


    guard let photo = arraySource[0]["photo"]
                else {
                    imageView.image = nil
                    self.view.viewWithTag(1005).hidden = false

                    return }

            let url = photo
            self.setImageFrom(link: url)
            self.view.viewWithTag(1005).hidden = true



                }


        }

func setImageFrom(link link:String) {
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL( NSURL(string:link)!, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if let data = data {

                    UIView.transitionWithView(self,
                        duration:0.5,
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
                        animations: {  self.image = UIImage(data: data) },
                        completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }


    }
```

Comment: Show your code for the setting labels and images in each cell.  That is likely where the memory use is.

Comment: I'm gathering from these code snippets that you have some conditional logic regarding if and when to add subviews. That's a prime candidate for problems. Rather than trying to remedying that code, though, I might suggest refactoring it out completely, using storyboards (like http://stackoverflow.com/a/28397009/1271826) or if not using storyboards, you can use NIBs (like http://stackoverflow.com/a/28490468/1271826).

Comment: @Putz1103 please check the edit 1