# Image Loading Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

Whenever I call this, the image still shows up blank as if it is nil. Am I setting the picture incorrectly? Help please. Thanks.

```
   var image = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UIImageView
    var title = cell.viewWithTag(102) as! UILabel
    var record = cell.viewWithTag(103) as! UILabel




   image.image = todo.image

       // image = UIImageView(image: newImage)

    if image.image == nil{
        print("nilish")
        image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "EmptyProfile.png"))
    }


    image.image = todo.image
    if image.image == nil{
        image.image = UIImage(named: "EmptyProfile.png")
    }
```

Comment: don't set imageview  maybe delete this `if image.image == nil{
        print("nilish")
        image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "EmptyProfile.png"))
    }` will work

Comment: By the way, are you getting to this code at all? Are you seeing any `print` statements showing up?

Comment: no. I never see it. Btw, I deleted that first snippet of code including nilish" and it didn't do anything @Rob

Comment: Just to be clear: Have you confirmed that this code is getting run at all? If not, maybe you neglected to set the delegate of the table view.

Comment: BTW, once you've fixed this issue, you might consider retiring the tag number approach and use a custom cell subclass, e.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28397009/1271826.